# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, sbt, spark-structured-streaming, spark-submit

i am doing spark structured streaming with kafka and cassandra while i am running below command i got an error

```
spark-submit --class StreamHandler --master local[*] --packages "org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.2.3" target/scala-2.12/stream-handler_2.12-1.0.jar
```

I am doing this project Ubuntu linux machine itself

```
causedby:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializerat java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 24 more
```

How to resolve the error?

My versions:

- spark - spark-3.2.3-hadoop2.7
- scala - 2.12.15
- kafka - kafka_2.12-2.8.0
- sbt - sbt-1.9.1

Comment: This serializer is part of the `org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients` so maybe you can try to add that package also from [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka-clients). `--packages` should pull dependencies itself, so this is weird.

Answer (score 0):

You should create an uber JAR with SBT that includes `kafka-clients` and `spark-sql-kafka-0-10`, rather than use `--packages`. Otherwise, you'll need to provide both.